# Passing arguments within an HTML environment

Tags: jquery, html

I've written a display engine (called mpv.html in the code) for pictures. It has two modes. Mode 1 shows individual images (linked with thumbnails) and mode 2 flips through an array of image names, something like a slideshow, triggered by a form submit.

All arguments are passed in the URL. In mode 1, the link calling mpv passes the image file name and desired additional data, but in mode 2 most of that data is suppressed and only the image file names are passed (as a string through the HTML Form mechanism).

In development (where mpv.html is in the same folder as the HTML pages offering the images), both modes work just fine. But on the server, although mode 1 works perfectly, mode 2 (where the display engine is in its own location on the same server) only sees "[display engine]?inp1=", where the value of inp1 should be a string of image file names. A test passing just simple characters also fails to show, so I'm forced to believe that the value of strTest, which is injected into the form before submitting, is not being seen by the display engine when in the server environment.

Is this a CORS problem? Whatever, does anyone see a more successful way of passing the array of file names?

```
.
.
.
<td><a href="../../mpv/mpv.html?pic=../WebTopics/dk1968_211.jpg&color=#4D4d4d&backcolor=..." target="_blank"><img src="images/dk1968_211_t.jpg"></a></td>
.
.
.
<form action="../../mpv/mpv.html" method="get" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" id="input1" name="inp1">
<input type="submit" value="Play as slide show...">
</form>
.
.
.
<script>
...
  arImages.push("../WebTopics/DavidsKids/images/dk1968_216.jpg");
...
var strTest = JSON.stringify(arImages);
$("#input1").val(strTest);
...
</script>
```

Comment: You need to URL-encode the `#` characters in the URL. They should be `%23`

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL-encode the `#` characters in the `href` URL. Otherwise, it's treated as a delimiter, and everything after it is the hash of the URL.

```
<a href="../../mpv/mpv.html?pic=../WebTopics/dk1968_211.jpg&color=%234D4d4d&backcolor=..." target="_blank">
```

Comment: Perhaps you misread my question. The link(s) to which you refer work just fine in both modes. It is the data sent via jQuery that isn't getting to the URL but only when on the server. And, by the way, I've learned that I must change any %23 to #, if I want the values to be read.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. There is no problem at all. My development environment contains a copy of jQuery, and the server environment did not.

All fixed.